# How to save outputs (from xarray) from python dask delayed into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, dask, python-xarray

I am very new to to trying to parallelize my python code. I am trying to perform some analysis on an xarray, then fill in a pandas dataframe with the results. The columns of the dataframe are independent, so I think it should be trivial to parallelise using dask delayed, but can't work out how. My xarrays are quite big, so this loop takes a while, and is big in memory. It could also be chunked by time, instead, if that's easier (this might help with memory)!

Here is the un-parallelized version:

```
from time import sleep
import time
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

data1 = np.random.rand(4, 3,3)
data2=np.random.randint(4,size=(3,3))

locs1 = ["IA", "IL", "IN"]
locs2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
times = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=4)

xarray1 = xr.DataArray(data1, coords=[times, locs1, locs2], dims=["time", "space1", "space2"])
xarray2= xr.DataArray(data2, coords=[locs1, locs2], dims=[ "space1", "space2"])

def delayed_where(xarray1,xarray2,id):
    sleep(1)
    return xarray1.where(xarray2==id).mean(axis=(1,2)).to_dataframe(id)

final_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=range(4),index=times)

for column in final_df:
    final_df[column]=delayed_where(xarray1,xarray2,column)
```

I would like to parallelize the for loop, but have tried:

```
final_df_delayed=pd.DataFrame(columns=range(4),index=times)

for column in final_df:
    final_df_delayed[column]=delayed(delayed_where)(xarray1,xarray2,column)

final_df.compute()
```

Or maybe something with dask delayed?

```
final_df_dd=dd.from_pandas(final_df, npartitions=2)
for column in final_df:
    final_df_dd[column]=delayed(delayed_where)(xarray1,xarray2,column)

final_df_dd.compute()
```

But none of these work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using delayed correctly, but it's not possible to construct a dask dataframe in the way you specified.

```py
from dask import delayed
import dask

@delayed
def delayed_where(xarray1,xarray2,id):
    sleep(1)
    return xarray1.where(xarray2==id).mean(axis=(1,2)).to_dataframe(id)

@delayed
def form_df(list_col_results):
    final_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=range(4),index=times)

    for n, column in enumerate(final_df):
        final_df[column]=list_col_results[n]
    return final_df

delayed_cols = [delayed_where(xarray1,xarray2, col) for col in final_df.columns]

delayed_df = form_df(delayed_cols)

delayed_df.compute()
```

Note that the enumeration is a clumsy way to get correct order of the columns, but your actual problem might guide you to a better way of specifying this (e.g. by explicitly specifying each column as an individual argument).

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this is exactly what I need. In particular, the bit I hadn't got my head around was also forming the dataframe in a delayed function, which then allows you to compute the whole thing at the end. Thanks also for introducing me to the @ notation, it's much cleaner than what I wrote.

Comment: You're welcome! If you use xarray, you might find this video useful, it seems like you are working with a very similar pattern: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84m0NlqJ_E0